# row wise pair calulations in R

Tags: r

I want to know the best way to this.

Using this format..

```
gene Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 ....
A   0 2 0
B   1 1 3
C 1.32 3.21 3.33
....
```

to that result

```
gene Sample1 Sample2 Sample3 ....
A-B -1 1 -3 
A-C -0.32 -2.21 -0.33
A-D
...
B-C
...
```

Give me an advice. Thanks!!

Data is too big but I want to handle it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Using `expand.grid()` is great for getting a dataframe with all combinations of different vectors. In this case, you want to get every combination of the vector with itself. This code does what you want to do but there's probably a faster way of doing it. For N = 1,000, it took 7 seconds on my machine.

```
set.seed(1)
N <- 5
d <- data.frame(gene = 1:N, sample.1 = sample(N), sample.2 = sample(N))
head(d)
     gene sample.1 sample.2
1    1        2        5
2    2        5        4
3    3        4        2
4    4        3        3
5    5        1        1

df <- expand.grid(list(d$gene, d$gene))
df <- merge(df, d, by.x = "Var1", by.y = "gene")
df <- merge(df, d, by.x = "Var2", by.y = "gene")
df$gene.diff <- paste(df$Var1, "-", df$Var2)
df$sample.1.diff <- df$sample.1.x - df$sample.1.y
df$sample.2.diff <- df$sample.2.x - df$sample.2.y

# Only need one difference between each pair of genes:
df <- df[df$Var1 > df$Var2, ]

df <- df[, names(df) %in% c("gene.diff", grep("diff", names(df), value = TRUE))]
head(df, n = 8)

        gene.diff sample.1.diff sample.2.diff
 2      2 - 1             3            -1
 3      3 - 1             2            -3
 4      4 - 1             1            -2
 5      5 - 1            -1            -4
 8      3 - 2            -1            -2
 9      4 - 2            -2            -1
 10     5 - 2            -4            -3
 14     4 - 3            -1             1
```

Comment: in part # Only need one difference between each pair of genes: If gene name isn't number, what can i do?

Comment: Instead of `d <- data.frame(gene = 1:N)` you could do `d <- data.frame(gene = unique(genes))`

Answer (score 1):

This solution eliminates the `merge` step and makes better use of matrix arithmetic.

```
#reproducible example!
data <- data.frame(gene=LETTERS[1:3], Sample1=c(0,1,1.321), 
                     Sample2 = c(2,1,3.21), Sample3=c(0,3,3.33))

# hooray for cartesian join
combos <- subset(merge(data,data,by=NULL, suffixes=c(".1",".2")), gene.1 != gene.2)

gene1_vals <- combos[,2:ncol(data)]
gene2_vals <- combos[,(ncol(data)+2):(2*ncol(data))]
gene_diff_txt <- paste(combos[,1], combos[,ncol(data)+1],sep="-")

gene_diffs <- data.frame(gene1_vals - gene2_vals)
names(gene_diffs) <- paste0("Sample",1:ncol(gene1_vals))
data.frame(gene=gene_diff_txt, gene_diffs)[order(combos$gene.1, combos$gene.2),]
#   gene Sample1 Sample2 Sample3
# 4  A-B  -1.000    1.00   -3.00
# 7  A-C  -1.321   -1.21   -3.33
# 2  B-A   1.000   -1.00    3.00
# 8  B-C  -0.321   -2.21   -0.33
# 3  C-A   1.321    1.21    3.33
# 6  C-B   0.321    2.21    0.33
```